# Generate number in sequential or random order for OfflineCommand with/without internet

Tags: codenameone

I'm using following code to generate the number to map the offlinecommands in Storage. I wondering there should be better way to handle or generate the numbers for storage in CN1. Please advise.

```
public String isRandomRetrieval() {
int actID = 0; 
int counterR = Preferences.get("counterR", 1000);
actID = ++counterR;
if (actID > 10000) {
actID = 1000;
}
Preferences.set("counterR", actID);
return "" + actID;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code so you'd be looking for a better approach? The number is sequential not random

Comment: Correct looking for a better approach. I was using -    Random ran = new Random();
int nxt = ran.nextInt(1000); I'm not sure this is accurate to use in offline mode, there are chances that this generation might have same values sometimes. IS there any better approach to do instead of setting a number and resetting to make sure it never exceeds the int size. Is there any library method available?

Comment: Normally I would use UUID but that isn't supported in Codename One. I wouldn't rely on random to make sure there is no collision. I would use a String instead of a number and use a unique device id assigned by the server as the prefix for every such key.